# Can't type after "ruby script/server" in InstantRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel

I'm a newb to RoR. I'm using the book "Agile Web Development with Rails" to get started on Windows 7.

In the command window, I run the following.

```
>rails demo
>cd demo
>ruby script/server
```

At this point, it boots the Mongrel server:

```
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

The book goes on to tell me to run

```
ruby script/generate controller Say
```

but, I cannot Ctrl-C -- or type anything for that matter -- after booting the Mongrel server. Am I supposed to create the new controller in another instance of the InstantRails command window? Right now, the only way I can stop the server is closing the window in which I started the server!

Please let me know if you need any other details. tia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always open a new window and run those commands from there.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to put the job in the background or fire up another shell. Control-C should still work, however.

Comment: How do I "put the job in the background"?

Comment: You're on Windows, so I have no idea.